# Sticks and stones may break my sum

Tags: mathematics, visual, calculation-puzzle

13 sticks and two stones are laid out as follows:

[image]

**Move three items** so the arrangement makes sense.

Only the basic functions `×÷-+=` are allowed.

Comment: @boboquack That would be allowed.

Comment: Can you make the stones more prominent, please? I missed them at first.

Comment: can we have / as divide?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil No

Comment: You might want to hold off accepting for a bit, so other people have a look at the puzzle.

Comment: @boboquack Fair enough. What's a good length of time to wait?

Comment: I usually wait until the puzzle is at least around 18 hours old, that gives most timezones a chance to view.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil done

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil why is accepting an answer prevents other people from viewing the puzzle?

Comment: @WilliamNathanael It doesn't - but less people are inclined to click on the link on the front page because of the acceptance of an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice puzzle! I found this:

> [image: proper answer]

### Edit breaks this old answer

If turning the = into an inequality or a congruence is allowed, we can do several things:

> [image: congruence]
>  [image: inequality]
>  (note with the second the movement of the decimal points is arbitrary, anything that would result in a valid expression will do, and also we can move any of the ones to the inequality cross, etc.)

Comment: I love the cheeky third solution.

Answer (score 7):

One way to solve this question:

> [image]Step 1

Answer (score 0):

When faced with a puzzle with multiple solutions I tend to choose the laziest solution.  [It's rarely what the op imagined](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/my-puzzle-was-answered-credibly-correctly-but-not-as-intended) but why work hard if you don't have to?

This solution meets these requirements:

- Move three items
- The arrangement makes sense
- Only the basic functions ×÷-+= are allowed
- Lazy

> [image]
>   
>  ✔ **Move three items:** 1 stick and 2 stones, rotated
>   
>  ✔ **The arrangement makes sense:** [22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/22_(number))
>   
>  ✔ **Only the basic functions ×÷-+= are allowed:** used ×-+
>   
>  ✔ **Lazy:** none of that heavy lifting

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure if I saw this I would think "makes sense". If anything, it would make me wonder the significance of n.

Comment: Don't see any requirement in the puzzle for significance. But if a pun will do I gave you 2 significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

I got this one:

> 1.1 x 11 - 11.1 = 1

Explanation:

> Take one stick from the equal sing and move it to the minus, so you get
>  1.1 x 11 - 11 = 1.1 The equation is true now, but the puzzle requires moving three items.
>  Take the last stick and stone from the last number and move them to the subtracted number 11, like so:
>  1.1 x 11 - 11.1 = 1

Comment: I'm just concerned that there wouldn't be enough space between the 11 and the equals to put an extra .1 there.

Comment: @boboquack true, didn't took that into consideration